# Anyone to upload a file to my Google Drive public folder using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, file-upload, google-drive-api, httprequest

I'm new to Google API. My goal is to allow website users to upload a file to our public Google Drive folder. I should do it on a client side.

I understand that it's not secure, but the team is pushing me to do it on a front-end.

I've read and tried different solutions (from StackOverflow answers as well), nothing works.

I've also checked Google Drive API documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

The request should like:

```
POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

JPEG data
```

I've tried to make a simple HTTP POST request in JavaScript, but couldn't set the `Host` header (unsecured header error).

Is `your_auth_token` a `client secret`?

Any ideas how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Anybody will be able to upload files to your Google Drive. Have you tried to publish and set `Who has access to the app` to **Anyone, even anonymous** ?

Comment: @d.datul1990 I'm not sure, but I think that this option is available only for Google Apps Script. Btw, I've done that via Google Script, but I need to integrate it into our Salesforce application, so I've just registered our app in the GoogleAPI console.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Google app to get your auth_token stick that in your request header and that should work fine.

How authorization works
At a high-level, all apps follow the same basic authorization pattern:

1. Register the application in the Google API Console.
2. Request that the user grant access to data in their Google account.
3. If the user consents, your application requests and receives
   credentials to
4. Access the Drive API.
5. Refresh the credentials (if necessary).

Creating new authentication

1. From the Credentials page, click Create credentials > OAuth client
   ID to create your OAuth 2.0 credentials or Create credentials >
   Service account key to create a service account.
2. If you created an OAuth client ID, then select your application
   type. Fill in the form and click Create.

Client keys are stored in here:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=drive&safe=vss&credential=client_key

Futher Documentation

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth

Comment: I've already created an app. I can authorize and upload a file to my own google drive, but...
Can I somehow skip the authorization or authorize to my Drive account automatically all the time to let users upload their files?

Comment: @Frelseren My experience is that probably isn't the best idea and maybe even impossible I honestly don't think Google would allow it, you could have a single shared auth_token?

Comment: I've almost accomplished that using https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample. Yes, we need an auth_token. My colleague started working on it on a back-end side.

Comment: @Frelseren Have you thought about creating a REST service that could act like a man in the middle and have have a single key for the service?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what we are going to try. I will post results later.